# NSURLConnection synchonous methods from within NSOperation

Tags: iphone, multithreading, concurrency, nsurlconnection, nsoperation

Suppose I have multiple NSOperation objects attached to a concurrent queue.

Within these NSOperations, I would call a synchronous method of NSURLConnectionClass, `sendSynchronousRequest ...` just to not mess up my code with tracing different connections from within a single delegate.

Apple says that `sendSynchronousRequest ...` is going to automatically create a separate thread with a run loop to trace NSURLConnection delegate messages.

But I already have several additional threads (running inside `NSOperation`)! So the question is: if I have, say, 10 `NSOperation` objects and each would call the synchronous method of `NSURLConnection`, will it produce 10 more additional ("automatically created") threads with run loops or there will be only **one** for all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry about the thread that `NSURLConnection` creates. It is some internal detail. I'm pretty sure it is one global thread shared by all `NSURLConnection` instances.